# Find the area of a geodesic triangle in the hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

The hyperbolic space of dimension 2 can be modeled via the upper half plane $H^2 = \{(u, v) \in \mathbb{R^2} | v > 0\}$
equipped with the metric $g(u, v) = \frac{1}{v^2} I_2$, with $I_2$ the identity matrix of dimension 2. Let's consider the geodesic triangle in $H^2$ whose vertices are lying all at infinity. It consists of the outside of a half circle of radius 1 and enclosed inside two vertical lines which start at one of the ends of the diameter of the half circle and are drawn to infinity in the same direction. I need to calculate the area of that triangle by integration. I am fully confused with the shape of the triangle, the bounds of the integral and I do not know how to proceed with calculating it's area. Can you provide some suggestion or a solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: One way is to use the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

Comment: I only want to use integration, without the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

Comment: The region of integration is exactly as you describe. The area form is $$ \frac{du\,dv}{v^2}. $$ At this point, you do the double integral exactly the way you did it in multivariable calculus. Probably you want to first integrate with respect to $v$ along each vertical line and then integrate the resulting function of $u$.

Comment: Did you take a multivariable calculus class? This is where you normally learn how to compute such integrals. If you forgot the material, pick up a textbook on multivariable calculus and do some reading.

Comment: You might find it easier to start with a concrete ideal triangle. Say the one bounded by $x=\pm1$. So you integrate over $-1<x<1$ and over $\sqrt{1-x^2}<y<\infty$. Then you either know that all Ideal triangles have equal area, or argue that every other ideal triangle is equivalent to this one under some isometry, or you tackle the general case directly based on what you learned from doing the simpler concrete example first.